# Show that $\int_0^{\pi /2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}=\int_0^{\pi /2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}=\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{4})}{2\sqrt{2 \pi}}$

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form

I am interested in showing  that:
$$\int_0^{\pi /2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}=\int_0^{\pi /2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}=\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{4})}{2\sqrt{2 \pi}}$$
I've come across this equality without anything else, would you please help me what I should do?

Comment: Using Gamma function.....

Comment: Could you explain how? I'm quite unsure how to transform $\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$ into $\int_0^{\pi /2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the substitution $u=\cos x$ gives
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos x}}
=\int_0^1\frac{du}{u^{1/2}(1-u^2)^{1/2}}.$$
Now let $t=u^2$ to get
$$\int_0^1\frac{du}{u^{1/2}(1-u^2)^{1/2}}
=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t^{3/4}(1-t)^{1/2}}=\frac12B(1/4,1/2)$$
where $B(x,y)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
In terms of the Gamma function,
$$\frac12B(1/4,1/2)=\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{2\Gamma(3/4)}
=\frac{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(1/4)}{2\Gamma(3/4)}.$$
From the identity
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac\pi{\sin\pi x}$$
we get
$$\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4)=\pi\sqrt2$$
and then
$$\frac{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(1/4)}{2\Gamma(3/4)}
=\frac{\Gamma(1/4)^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$